# Understanding Promises in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I was trying to comprehend the use of Promise in Javascript for which Google search [lead me to this article](https://codeburst.io/javascript-learn-promises-f1eaa00c5461)

The author of post points out this

> Promises (like callbacks) allow us to wait on certain code to finish
>   execution prior to running the next bit of code.

Which for some reason sounded like this to me  (and it porbably might be)

```
  axios.get(url).then((response) => ).catch((err) =>
```

Thereafter he showed this example

```
function delay(t){
  return new Promise(function(resolve){
    return setTimeout(resolve, t)
  });
}
function logHi(){
  console.log('hi');
}
delay(2000).then(logHi);
```

Here, I am unable to comprehend what/how are we passing something in resolve here `function(resolve)` and when do we use something like

```
 return new Promise(function(resolve){
```

and when do we do something like

```
  axios.get(url).then((response) => ).catch((err) =>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example code isn't great because the promise doesn't actually resolve a value -- so nothing is passed to the `then()`. The function passed to `then` isn't expecting a value either. It's just waiting and logging 'hi'. So basically it's a timer with no resolved values.

If you want values passed around, you need to `resolve` and actual value:

It would be a more instructive example if they returned a value and then explicitly used that value. Something more like:

```js
function delay(t) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    return setTimeout(() => resolve("some value from promise"), t)
  });
}

function logHi(text) {
  console.log(text);
}
delay(1000).then(logHi)
// alternatively the same result as:
// delay(1000).then(value => logHi(value));
```

The code above uses a promise that we manually created because we wanted to resolve something after `setTimeout` which does not return a promise of it's own. It essentially *promisifies* `setTimeout`. When you use a library like axios, it's `get` method already returns a promise, so you can just use it like:

```
 axios.get(url).then((response) => )
```

There's no need (and in fact it's an anti-pattern) to wrap it in another `new Promise`. You can just take the promise returned from `get()` and call `then()` on that promise.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Also If you can add this to your answer. When do we use (or difference between) `return new Promise(function(resolve){` and  `axios.get(url).then((response) => ).catch((err) => `

Comment: Hey @KuchBhi I added a bit about the different about `axios.get()` and `new Promise()`…hope it's clear.

Comment: You are champ @Mark. Thanks a lot :)